# How to delay pipe netcat to connect on first input

Tags: linux, pipe, netcat

Running in bash under Ubuntu:

I have a source that generates me some output, but not straight away. Let's assume it is a first netcat listening on a socket: `netcat -l 12345`.

And I would like to pipe it to an outgoing netcat (connecting over TCP), e.g. `netcat -l 12345 | netcat localhost 54321`. But the tricky bit is, that I know there is nothing listening for that incoming connection on localhost 54321 when I run the command, but I know there will be one when the first actual character arrives through the pipe.

So my question is: is there a way either:

- to delay the execution of the outgoing netcat until the first character arrives into the pipe, or
- to delay the outgoing netcat from trying to establish the TCP connection until it receives the first character on its standard input? (no straight option for that in man, switching to UDP is not acceptable)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: In reality, the source is more complex than a netcat, namely it is a listening netcat piped through all sort of stream modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the research you already did and that I commented to (by not knowing it was an answer to your own question), here is the full `delayed_netcat.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
netcat "${@}" < <(echo $line ; cat)
```

This first waits for a line of input and later prepends that line using a simple `echo` to the "newly generated" input to the actual `netcat`. The rest of stdin is just redirected using `cat` which slurps it from `stdin` and adds it to the input of `netcat`. It also supports passing commandline options and arguments to the "real" `netcat`.

The usage is as follows:

```
netcat -l 12345 | cmd1 | cmd2 | ... | ./delayed_netcat.sh localhost 54321
```

The `netcat` is delayed till the first line is read. If you really want to start it after the first character is read the parts with `read` and `echo` need some rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, it's one of those questions where we can always wait for more improvements, nicer syntax, but I'm going to accept yours, as it does the trick and is nicer than my own proposal.

Answer (score 1):

[Port Forwarding or Port Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Port_Forwarding_or_Port_Mapping) with netcat:

```
ncat -l -p 12345 -c 'ncat localhost 54321'
```

Using [`socat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345 TCP4:localhost:54321
```

This command exits after the first connection is done.

Comment: The problem is not exiting after the first connection is done, it is not starting the outgoing connection until there is something to actually send on it. And in reality, I am not doing simple port forwarding, because I am modifying the stream between the netcats, so I need the possibility to pipe more script in between...

Comment: @Balint: both commands delay the connection to 54321 until something is written to 12345 as you've asked. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15809098/edit) to include the part about "the possibility to pipe more script in between."

Comment: @Sebastian: Ok, true, could try it and this is very useful to know even without the pipes working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question, but it is awful... so still looking for something better.

`netcat -l 12345 | gawk '(NR==1){print""}{print;fflush()}' | ./delayed_netcat.sh`

where `./delayed_netcat.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
read line
netcat localhost 12345
```

So the `read line` delays the `netcat localhost 12345` by waiting for and consuming the first input line, and I use `gawk '(NR==1){print""}{print;fflush()}'` to insert an empty line just before the first record... I'm sure there is room for much improvement to that!

Comment: you can just add the line back to the input like in `netcat localhost 12345 < <(echo $line ; cat)` within `./delayed_netcat.sh`