# how to make netcat server respond to a different port

Tags: udp, netcat

I need to simulate a scenario (under UDP, if if  matters)

1)nc server listens on port 9000 (ncserver1)
2)nc client connects to nc server and sends "message1" and simultaneously another nc server is started and is listening on port 9001 (ncserver2)
3)On receiving "message1" the ncserver1 should initiate connection to ncserver2 and send "message2"
4)ncserver2 receives the message "mess"

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting scenario.  The first thing to do is start netcat on 9000 waiting for message1. sed is used to filter out all messages that are not message1 and to create message2 to be sent out when message1 is received.

```
nc -u -l -p 9000 | sed -un 's/message1/message2/p' |./delayed_netcat.sh  -u localhost 9001
```

delayed_netcat.sh is a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817571/1467387) from mariux

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
netcat "${@}" < <(echo $line ; cat)
```

which delays connecting to 9001 until it has something to send.

Next we start another netcat listening on 9001 and at the same time send message1 to 9000

```
nc -u -l -p 9001 | sed -un "s/message2/mess/p" &  echo "message1" |nc -u localhost 9000
```

Here sed is used to look for message2 and output mess.